# Why doesn't Number(window.prompt) convert the string to an integer

Tags: javascript

For example: Run the code and enter input "99" and see the console it prints NaN

```js
var numberOne= Number(window.prompt("Type a number", ""));
    //in prompt I entered "99" and I get output NaN
    console.log(numberOne);

    var numberTwo = "99";
    console.log(Number(numberTwo));
```

Why am I getting **NaN** when I use Number with **prompt**

Comment: Your code works.https://jsfiddle.net/812yp3wj/

Comment: Try `console.log(Number(numberOne));` instead of  `console.log(numberOne);` or `parseInt`

Comment: the code works, but if you want to calculate anything before it is a number you need to parse it first

Comment: I think the question should be reframed -- Why doesn't Number(window.prompt) convert the string to an integer, the way it does in the second example.

Comment: @LarryTurtis Thanks, I edited the question.

Comment: it still works :)

Comment: It "works" if you input 99 (no quotes) to the prompt, but if you input "99" with quotes, you get NaN.

Comment: @LarryTurtis If the input can be "99", the input can be 99% too, and 99// or anything else. This is not the way to go. If this is the problem, validate the entry to accepty only numbers.

Comment: I don't think anyone is advocating anything. I think this is a general question about why Javascript behaves this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Number() function converts the object argument to a number that
>   represents the object's value.
>
> **Returns:** A Number. Returns different object values to their numbers.
>   If the value cannot be converted to a legal number, NaN is returned.
>   If no argument is provided, it returns 0.

I assume you're entering *99* (without the quotes). If you're entering with quotes you'd need to parse and/or validate the input.

```js
var numberOne = Number(window.prompt("Try 99 (with number conversion)", ""));
if (numberOne === 99) console.log('The string 99 has converted successfully!');

numberOne = window.prompt("Try 1 (No Number-convesion)", "");
if (numberOne === 1) console.log('The string 1 has converted successfully!');
else console.log('The string 1 did not convert to a number (int)');
```

In the second example, "1" does not convert to a type of number (int). This is evident since the comparison is type sensitive (`===` instead of `==`).

**In short:** your code works as expected.

Comment: var numberOne = window.prompt("Try 99", "");
if (numberOne == 99){
 alert('The string has converted successfully!');
} how these two are different?

Comment: @JagadeshaNH Not sure I understand ... they're not different. Edit: and the missing `Number` will make it not convert to a type of number. I'll update this example too.

Comment: I removed Number and it still works, that's what I am asking.

Comment: @JagadeshaNH I updated the example to illustrate. When comparing with `==` javascript automatically convert to appropriate types. When using `===` you're comparing the type of the data too.

Comment: I know the difference between == and === , anyways my doubt was different. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because window.prompt already returns a string. So when you enter "99", you are effectively trying to cast `'"99"'` to a Number, which can't be done.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

**Please note that result is a string. That means you should sometimes cast the value given by the user. For example, if his answer should be a Number, you should cast the value to Number.**

Comment: Thanks Larry. But, I don't understand why this question was down voted by others, If they can't understand the question.

Comment: Regarding the bold part: `Number()` does convert to an appropriate type. Apparently it can't convert `'"99"'` to an int, but I doubt _parseInt_ would do much better. This is more of a validation concern.

Answer (score -1):

window.prompt() returns a string for you

from code

```
var numberOne= Number(window.prompt("Type a number", ""));
```

if you input `99`, variable `numberOne` will be `"99"`, that you want. and this value can convert be number `99` using `Number()`

but if you input `"99"`, variable `numberOne` will be `""99""` and cannot convert to number.